# ActiveMq ,How to auto delete received or expired Topic message in Mysql?

Tags: activemq-classic

ActiveMq 5.10 and persistence in Mysql5.5.

I create a topic, use *publisher.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)* to send 5 messages,and  2 durableSubscribers already received all of the messages.

then. these is a problem:
those 5 messages still there ,they dont delete by MQ. and I worry about too many messages cause a crash. 
I also find out when activemq restart, those 5 messages gone. and same happened when I use a queue.

**question :**
how to delete those received or expired (in topic) messages in datebase automeaticlly or manually ?

Comment: Not enough details to demonstrate what you are asking.  How do you support the assertion that consumed messages are not removed.

Comment: i found consumed msg.  and exp. msg. delete after a few hours. no problem any more.